# updating mysql via values of associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I got an database that looks like

```
COUNTRY RATES   
AUD     0.5
BRL     1.2
CAD     1.6
CHF     1.4
CZK     2.5
```

now i want to update the rates using this array

```
$rates = array (
    'AUD' => '0.5',
    'BRL' => '6.2',
    'CAD' => '2.6',
    'CHF' => '7.4',
    'CZK' => '1.5',
 );
```

i tried using this code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "eurotoforgein";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$table = 'rates';


$values = "'" . implode("','", array_values($rates)) . "'";

$sql = "UPDATE `eurotoforgein` SET 'RATES' WHERE rates =  $values";



if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){ 

die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']'); 

}

else{
echo "Data Updated.";
}
```

but i get 
There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''RATES' WHERE rates = '0.5','1.2','1.6','1.4','2.5'' at line 1]

any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my solution:

```
$sql = '';
$rates = array (
    'AUD' => '0.5',
    'BRL' => '6.2',
    'CAD' => '2.6',
    'CHF' => '7.4',
    'CZK' => '1.5',
 );
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "eurotoforgein";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

foreach($rates as $iso=>$rate){
$sql .= "UPDATE `eurotoforgein` SET `RATES`='{$rate}' WHERE COUNTRY = '{$iso}'";
}

if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){ 

die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']'); 

}else{
echo "Data Updated.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to update those values one by one. This should help you on the way:

```
foreach ($rates as $country => $rate) {
  $sql = "update rates set RATES = $rate where COUNTRY = $country";
  // execute
}
```

Have a look at the UPDATE syntax if you want to learn more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL queries comes out like this:

```
UPDATE `eurotoforgein` SET 'RATES' WHERE rates = '0.5','6.2','2.6','7.4','1.5'
```

That's not valid SQL.

Build your query this way:

```
$sql = '';
foreach($rates as $country => $value){
    $sql .= "UPDATE `eurotoforgein` SET `rates` = '$value' WHERE `country` =  '$country';";
}
```

This creates a string containing multiple UPDATE queries and can be executed in

1 go, $conn->query($sql);